# In Foundry Workshop, how do I save and writeback all values set within a Scenario?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios, foundry-workshop

I've created a Scenario in Foundry Workshop and would like to save all of the values set in the Scenario to a dataset for further processing or display.

How do I configure my Scenario so that its values are written back to a backing dataset like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this task:

1. You can save the Scenario as a an object. See https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-save/#saving-scenarios-as-a-user for the relevant documentation.
2. You can also apply the actions in a Scenario to the Ontology. See https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-apply/ for the relevant documentation.

It is not currently possible to write the values from a saved Scenario to a dataset, but if the Scenario is applied the changes will appear in the writeback dataset as normal.